# if a certain value is same assign a specific value to all other occurrences python

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temporary table called #havehu wherein there is data of patient, PersonID,  encounters, and ICDcodes. There is a column called enterocolitis whose values are 1 and 0. In other words, if a patient is suffering from enterocolitis he/she is assigned 1 and if the patient is not suffering he/she is assigned 0.
I need to achieve this - If a person is having 1 for any of the encounters he/she has to be assigned 1 for all the encounters.

Note - The person id is the same for the patient, but the encounter id changes for every visit. Also, I have more than 7000 patients and 35,000 encounters

Comment: . . I removed the "mysql" tag because `#havehu` is a valid temporary table name in SQL Server but not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses updatable CTEs and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select h.*,
             max(Entrocolitis) over (partition by Personid) as person_e
      from #havehu h
     )
update toupdate
    set Entrocolitis = max_e
    where Entrocolitis is null or Entrocolitis <> max_e;
```